# "sequenced before" and "Every evaluation in the calling function" in c++

Tags: c++

Every evaluation in the calling function (including other function calls) that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or after the execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately sequenced with respect to the execution of the called function.

In other words, function executions do not interleave with each other.

what is the meaning of "Every evaluation".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int a = 0;
ing b = 0;
int f(int,int)
{
    cout << "call f, ";
    cout << "a=" << a << ", ";
    cout << "b=" << b << ", ";
    return 1;
}

int g()
{
    cout << "call g, ";
    cout << "a=" << a << ", ";
    cout << "b=" << b << ", ";
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    f(a++, b++) + g();
    return 0;
}
```

1. it menas evaluation of function call expression `f(a++, b++)`, so evaluation of a++, evaluation of b++, and execution of f are all sequenced before or after the execution of g.

   In this case, there are two kinds of results. If evaluation of expression f(a++, b++) is sequenced before the execution of g:

   `call f, a=1, b=1, call g, a=1, b=1,`

   If execution of g issequenced before evaluation of expression f(a++, b++):

   `call g, a=0, b=0, call f, a=1, b=1,`

2.It means evaluation of a++, evaluation of b++, or execution of f.

So evaluation of a++ may be sequenced before execution of g, evaluation of b++ and execution of f may be sequenced after execution of g.

```
call g, a=1, b=0, call f, a=1, b=1,
```

3. It means value computation or side effect.

So value computation of a++ may be sequenced before execution of g, side effect of a++, evaluation of b++ and execution of f may be sequenced after execution of g.

```
call g, a=0, b=0, call f, a=1, b=1,
```

In this case,

```
f(a++, b++) + (a = g());
1.value computation of a++
2.execution of g
3.side effect of a++
4.side effect of = (a = 0)
5.evaluation of b++
6.execution of f

call g, a=0, b=0, call f, a=0, b=1,
```

Which one is right? Or other answer?

I'm not an English speaker, and I'm not very good at English.

I hope you can understand what i say

f(h1(), h2()) + g(h3(), h4())

h1 and h2 are sequenced before f, h3 and h4 are sequenced before g.

Is it possible:

1. h1
2. h4
3. h2
4. f
5. h3
6. g

Comment: `f` and `g` can be executed in either order. The evaluation of `a++` and `b++` shall be completed (including the side effects) before `f` is called, but is indeterminately sequenced with `g`.

Comment: #2 and #3 cannot happen - it's explicitly prohibited by **[expr.post.incr]/1**: "With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of postfix `++` is a single evaluation. [ *Note:* Therefore, a function call shall not intervene between the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and the side effect associated with any single postfix `++` operator. *—end note* ]" Inside `f`, `a` and `b` must be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[expr.post.incr]/1** ... The value computation of the `++` expression is sequenced before the modification of the operand object. With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function call, the operation of postfix
>   `++` is a single evaluation. [ *Note:* Therefore, a function call shall not intervene between the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and the side effect associated with any single postfix `++` operator. *—end note* ]...

My reading of this is that the side effects of `a++` and `b++` must complete before the body of `f` is executed, and therefore within `f` it must be that `a==1` and `b==1`. Your examples #2 and #3 are not possible with a conforming implementation.

A call to `g` is indeterminately sequenced with a call to `f`, and thus can observe either pre-increment or post-increment values.

Comment: so f(h1(),h2())+g(),h1 and h2 are sequenced before or after g. h1 is sequenced before g but h2 is sequenced after g never happen?In other words,can value computation and side effect
associated with any argument expression from different function interleave with each other

Comment: I think it might be possible that `h1` is called first (and its return value cached in a register, say), then `g`, then `h2` and then `f`. I don't see what might prohibit it. In your original example, it seems possible that `a` is incremented first (with its pre-increment value cached in a register, say), then `g` is called, then `b` is incremented, then `f` is called. All that's guaranteed is that `f(0, 0)` is called, and that within f, `a == b == 1`. The paragraph I cite prohibits delaying the side-effect of increment until after `f` is called.

Comment: If I understand your notation correctly, example 2 assumes `b == 0` inside the body of `f`. This shouldn't be possible.

Comment: I wanted to know the oder between arguments of a function f and another function g. They are unsequenced. f(h1(), h2()) + g(h3(), h4()), h1 and h2 are sequenced before f, h3 and h4 are sequenced before g, so h2,h4,h1,f,h3,g may happen. And example 3 is wrong because [expr.post.incr]/1. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
f(a++, b++) + g();
```

Compiler can decide the order of execution of `f()` and `g()` in the above statement.

These are only 2 possibilities not 3.

Either `f()` will call first and modifies variables `a` and `b`
OR 
`g()` will get call first.

Comment: you mean 2. and 3. never happen?